# Prove that a number is not an exact cube by using modular arithmetic mod 9

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

My textbook asks me to prove that the number $$1\underbrace{000\ldots0}_{2012}5\underbrace{000\ldots0}_{2012}1$$ 
is not an exact cube of any natural number. And in the answers section it states that one shall use the properties of modulo 9, however I can't understand, why the number 9 is chosen for the task. Why don't we relate modulo 7? Or 11? I.e. why is the number 9 so special that we can use its residues' properties to prove whether a number is a cube?

Comment: A number $\equiv 7\pmod{9}$ cannot be a perfect cube.

Comment: While the remainders $\mod 7$ or $\mod 11$ do not give us such strong information.

Comment: One thing is that $(3a+b)^3 = 9(3a^3+3a^2b+ab^2) + b^3$, which means that it only can be $0$, $1$ or $8$ (mod 9).

Comment: We got "lucky" with the number $9$.

Comment: The only special property of $9$ that is being used here is that it's very easy to compute the residue mod $9$ of a large number, especially when most of its digits are $0$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing modulo 9 has two relevant properties:

- In base ten, it is *very easy* to reduce a large number modulo 9, because the result is just the iterated digit sum.
  So the large number in your exercise has residue $1+5+1=7$ modulo $9$.
- The only cubes modulo $9$ are $0$, $1$ and $8$, which you can check simply by taking the cube of each integer from $0$ to $8$. (This can made somewhat faster by noting that the cubes of $5,6,7,8$ are simply the negatives of the cubes of $4,3,2,1$).

Since $7$ is not in $\{0,1,8\}$, the large number is not a perfect cube.

---

Actually, computing modulo $7$ would work for this case too: The only cubes modulo $7$ are $\{0,1,6\}$, and your number is congruent to $4 \pmod 7$. But finding that $4$ takes quite a bit more effort than just summing digits.

Computing modulo $11$ would *not* teach us anything, because *every* residue class modulo $11$ is a possible cube. (This again can be seen by explicit computation, or with a bit of abstract algebra knowledge: $11$ is prime, so $\mathbb Z_{11}$ is a finite field, so its multiplicative group is cyclic of order $10$, which is coprime to $3$. So raising to the third power in $\mathbb Z_{11}$ is a bijection).

---

As Lee Mosher points out, it is not *always* the case that modulo $9$ works best. If we want to find out whether
$$ \underbrace{777\ldots777}_{2013}4 $$
is a cube, a modulo-9 test will be inconclusive (the number is congruent to $1$ modulo 9), but a modulo-7 test immediately tells us it can't be a cube.

Comment: Thank you so much; the case with modulo 9 was actually very frequent for this kind of proofs and yeah, I was wondering if the convenience to use this modulo is connected with the ease of calculating the digit sum to evaluate the residue.

Comment: $\bmod 13$ also works; remainder is $10$ which is not a cubic residue. (And again of course $3\mid (13-1)$ giving the reduced set of cubic residues).

Answer (score 2):

There is no assertion that $9$ can be used to prove whether any number is a cube.

There is only an assertion that $9$ can be used to prove that *this* number is *not* a cube, which is easy enough to check, because this number is congruent to $7$ modulo $9$, and $7$ is not a cube modulo $9$.

All this problem is saying is that working in arithmetic modulo $9$ is sufficient to prove that this number is not a cube. You can of course explore interesting mathematical questions such as: what other bases $n$ can be used in which to prove that this number is not a cube modulo $n$?